# How to delete empty space from a text file using python?

Tags: python, flask, text

[Image of the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21pdA.png)

Now what I want in this text file is the complete text written in a single line so that it looks like this one:[What I want it to be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN1o5.png)
How do I do this using python? I tried strip function ,replace function etc. It isnt just working.

Comment: Show your (failing) code and what result it produces.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to read the file in, remove the new lines and write it again.

```py
with open("./foo.txt", "r") as f:
    formatted = ""
    for line in f.readlines():
        formatted += line.replace('\n', " ") # Removes the new lines, add spaces instead
    
    formatted.replace("  ", " ") # Replace double space with one space
    
    # Writes single line to textfile
    with open("./bar.txt", "w") as out:
        out.write(formatted)
```